# How do you express any radical root of a number?

Tags: phrase-request, mathematics

I'm writing a reference for my piece of code, and one of the sentences is bugging me. The line I'm trying to express is something like:

> The value is raised to the power of the reciprocal of x.

Did you get that I was trying to mean **radical root** on the first try (for example, if x = 2, the value will be square-rooted?) I think this line is little too complex for some people to read. I'm writing a document that can possibly be read by anyone (even people whose mother tongue isn't English,) so I want to be as clear as possible.

The sentence would be simpler if there were an expression I can use to represent any radical root. just as simple as `2^5` expressed as

> 2 to the power of 5

However, I haven't been able to find any. Are there any, or do I have to stick with "to the power of?"

Comment: We usually include the suffix ***-th*** for clarity, so most commonly it's [*the **nth** root*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+nth+root+of%22). Since *the **xth** root* would be a bit of a mouthful, that would probably usually be written as *the **x** root*, but I bet many writers would simply change their example context to use ***n*** rather than ***x***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "x-th" is no more of a mouthful than "sixth", you might find the /s/ gets dropped in speech and it'll be pronounced /ekθ/ or /sɪkθ/ Then again, you might not.

Comment: @Au101: I kinda doubt many native speakers actually enunciate the /s/, but that's not much of a problem with SIKTH because we hear and say it enough so people get used to it. But EKTH just sounds a bit weird, and I at least feel a stronger urge to *attempt* the full enunciation even though my mouth isn't really up to the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are referring to the following equation:

[image]

.... the inverse function of a<sup>n</sup>

That being the case, in mathematics it is referred to as the **n<sup>th</sup> root of a number**, in this case the number being *a*.

In spoken form, one would say (for the values of n given)

> - (n=4) the fourth root of a
> - (n=5) the fifth root of a
> - (n=6) the sixth root of a
> - (n=7) the seventh root of a

...and so on. There are two exceptions, when n=2 or n=3. Here we would say:

> - (n=2) the **square** root of a
> - (n=3) the **cube** root of a

Comment: Yes, that's the right equation. One question - if x is not an integer (like 1.5, it can happen with my piece of code,) does it still make sense?

Comment: Good question. If you're looking for an abstract term, then **nth root** should cover it. For example, if a sentence read *'...and the answer is the nth root of 5, where n=1.5...'*, it seems perfectly acceptable to me at least.

Answer (score 0):

You have to say

> The value is raised to the power of 1/x.

Or spoken aloud:

> The value is raised to the power of one over x.

Mathematicians don't talk about "xth roots" when x is not an integer.

For positive integers n, "nth root" (pronounced "enth root") is fine.